# How do I get a list of videos which I like on youtube?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, api, youtube-api

In the Youtube API, How do I get a list of videos which I like?

Is there any API call available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch a user profile, the returned data structure contains a url which contains that users favourites. See Youtube API reference: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles.html and http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_gd:feedLink

Note though, that without authentication, you can only work on public profiles/favourites.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "favorite videos", this is mentioned in the API documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#User_favorites_feed